# Java and Hibernate error. Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipse, hibernate, orm

I try to use Hibernate 6.0 in Java 8 with Postgres, but I got this error: Could not access Unsafe class: sun.misc.Unsafe
How can I solve it?

````
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
    at net.bytebuddy/net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:154)
    at net.bytebuddy/net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:365)
    at net.bytebuddy/net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:174)
    at net.bytebuddy/net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:376)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.0.0.Alpha6/org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.load(ByteBuddyState.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.0.0.Alpha6/org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.loadProxy(ByteBuddyState.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.0.0.Alpha6/org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyHelper.buildProxy(ByteBuddyProxyHelper.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.0.0.Alpha6/org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyFactory.postInstantiate(ByteBuddyProxyFactory.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.0.0.Alpha6/org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.StandardPojoEntityRepresentationStrategy.createProxyFactory(StandardPojoEntityRepresentationStrategy.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.0.0.Alpha6/org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.StandardPojoEntityRepresentationStrategy.<init>(StandardPojoEntityRepresentationStrategy.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.0.0.Alpha6/org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.StandardManagedTypeRepresentationResolver.resolveStrategy(StandardManagedTypeRepresentationResolver.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.0.0.Alpha6/org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:695)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.0.0.Alpha6/org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:141)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.0.0.Alpha6/org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:97)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Could not access Unsafe class: sun.misc.Unsafe
    at net.bytebuddy/net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe$Dispatcher$Unavailable.initialize(ClassInjector.java:2006)
    at net.bytebuddy/net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe.injectRaw(ClassInjector.java:1738)
    at net.bytebuddy/net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$AbstractBase.inject(ClassInjector.java:110)
    at net.bytebuddy/net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$ForUnsafeInjection.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:567)
    at net.bytebuddy/net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:100)
    at net.bytebuddy/net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:6156)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.0.0.Alpha6/org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.lambda$load$0(ByteBuddyState.java:179)
    at net.bytebuddy/net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:152)
    ... ```
````

Comment: Why are you using 6.0? It is still under development. Can you use the latest stable version 5.4 - https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/ ?

Comment: I got the same error in the 5.4. Also I use byte-buddy-1.8.12.jar instead of byte-buddy-1.10.10.jar

Comment: Hmm...can you share the pom file or if possible a demo app for troubleshooting.

Comment: I'm not use pom file. This is module-info.java file:

`module WordTest {
 requires java.desktop;
 requires java.base;
 requires java.persistence;
 
 //для Hibernate
 requires java.sql;
 requires java.xml.bind;
 requires java.activation;
 requires com.sun.xml.bind;
 requires org.glassfish.jaxb.core;
 requires net.bytebuddy;
 requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
 
 //Для MS Office
 requires poi.ooxml.schemas;
 requires poi.ooxml;
 requires xmlbeans;
 
 
 
 requires com.fasterxml.classmate;
 
 exports MainPack to org.hibernate.orm.core;
 
}`

Comment: This is definitely NOT using java 8 as you claim. There are module names in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following command line flag when running the Java process to enable access to the Unsafe class: `--add-modules jdk.unsupported`